# Need AIX command to extract a particular text file from a compressed file

Tags: aix, gzip

I am looking for an AIX command to extract a particular text file from a compressed file.

For example, my compressed file `abc.gz` contains millions of files with multiple sub directories. I need to extract a single file using the wildcard. could someone please help.

- Compressed File: `abc.gz`
- Need to extract files like: `%defg%`

Comment: *How* does it contain millions of files? Is it a tar ball? is it a zip file? Unless you know (and tell us) the structure of what `abc.gz` contains, the only thing you can do is uncompress it with gzip and look through it with a text editor.

Comment: Possibly also .cpio.gz. The key fact is that .gz files contain a cumulative (and implicit) decoding table, which can only be reconstructed by decompressing the whole file. There is no way to decompress any arbitrary part of the file, even if you can find where it starts.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between compression of files and archiving of files.

**Compression** *is the reduction of volume of a file*.

**Archiving** *is storing of one of multiple files in an archive file with or without compression*.

A file with extention '.gz' is a compressed file. So your task sounds incorrect.

But in *nix environments we often use compression of a tar archive, usually such a file has '.tar.gz' or '.tgz' extention. Also there can be a different type of archive compressed (or different extention used).

So I guess you ask how to extract a file from a compressed archive. But to answer your question, some more details about a type of your archive required.